# TFS logout programmatically

Tags: c#

How can I log out from TFS 2012 (Cloud) from code?

Tried some things but Identity Provider always loading same credentials.

**UPDATE:** 
Some code i tried already

```
ClientCredentials tfsClientCredentials = new TfsClientCredentials(false);
TfsConfigurationServer serverConfig = new TfsConfigurationServer(uri, tfsClientCredentials);
serverConfig.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

and second snippet

```
TfsConfigurationServer serverConfig = new TfsConfigurationServer(uri, new UICredentialsProvider());
serverConfig.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

and third one

```
ICredentialsProvider provider = new UICredentialsProvider();
WindowsCredential wcred = new WindowsCredential(cred, provider);
TfsClientCredentials tfsClientCredentials = new TfsClientCredentials(wcred);
TfsConfigurationServer serverConfig = new TfsConfigurationServer(uri, tfsClientCredentials);
serverConfig.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

Comment: Show code you tried to work.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this.  I am having the same issue, the AuthenticatedUser will change, but the AuthorizedUser always stays the same.